# LabVIEW variable array size in SubVIs on FPGA

Tags: arrays, fpga, labview

I have acquisition code running on an cRIO FPGA target. The data is acquired from the I/O nodes and composed to an array. This array should always be of the same size thus I check that with a SubVI. The problem is that I use conditional disable structures to replace the acquistion code for different targets with different channel numbers. Now the compiler complains that it can't resolve the array to a fixed size which is not true because it could be counted by the compiler very easy.

How do I have to write my SubVI that it accepts a (at compile time) variable array? The "array size" symbol from the array palett can do this too. How?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the offending code, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lookup tables instead to achieve your goal. Or if you have to send this array to RT vi it would be more professional to use DMA FIFO instead. At RT side you can use polling method and read as many points you like at a time.

Comment: I use a DMA FIFO to send the data to the RT but I need to check the data first. I have to look into the lookup tables but can they be used with FXP values?

Answer (score 1):

In short this is not possible with standard LabVIEW arrays as the size must be fixed for compilation (as these basically come down to wires in the chip).

There are two options when you actually need a variable size:

1. **Simple and Wasteful** - If there is a reasonable upper bound you can set it to the highest and use logic to control the "end". This means compiling resources for the upper end and if it is more than 100's of bytes will use up a lot of logic.
2. **Scalable but slightly harder** - The only way to achieve a large variable size array is to use some of the memory options available with some added logic for defining the size. Depending on the size you can either use look up tables (LUTs) or block RAM. Again LUTs use up logic quickly so should only be used for small arrays (Can't remember the exact size recommended but probably < 500 bytes). If you've not used it you can find some initial reading at http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371599H-01/lvfpgaconcepts/fpga_storing_data/#Memory_Items

Either way you will have to somehow pass the subVI the size of the array so it knows how far into the memory to ready, this would have to simply be another input.

More commonly in LabVIEW FPGA most processing is done on point-by-point data so you can centralise the storage logic without having to pass this around, however this depends on the nature of the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your post but they are fixed for compilation, only the compiler doesn't get it. The SubVI has a variable input to match any number of elements in an array. And this could be converted to a fixed size array at compile time by checking the input form the wire.

At the moment I have three different input sizes hardcoded but I would like to know how to write this subVI more generic to reduce the overall changes if I have to measure an other node too.

Comment: I see what you mean. The array size is the property of the control so the fixed size won't propogate across subVI boundaries as you have told it at the subVI level it is variable size.

Technically you are right, it should be resolvable at compile time but I think this maybe a limitation of how LabVIEW works in this case.